# where is the ajaxfileupload.js for using with jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am looking for the ajaxfileupload.js file used in this question:
[File upload with jqgrid in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931468/file-upload-with-jqgrid-in-php?answertab=active#tab-top)
The referenced website (www.phpletter.com) seems to not exist anymore.
Who could give me a reference ?
Thank you by advance

Comment: Site works for me, here is the direct link http://www.phpletter.com/download_project_version.php?version_id=34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fbfcn provided a direct link to the project you are looking for.

However, [here](https://gist.github.com/2776054) is a copy of the JS file, in case you are having problems accessing the site directly.

Comment: could you give me the description of this plugin because the above cited example is wrong ... Thank you