# Upload File with Jqgrid and Ajaxfileupload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm working with a jqgrid and I would like to upload a file (pictures and pdf's). I've seen a lot of examples but nothing... I'd like to do un ajaxfileupload. Here is my code,

```
 colModel: [
        { name: "id", index:"id", key: true,width: 30,editable: false },

        { name: "name", index:"name", width: 100,editable: true },           
        { name: "fileToUpload", 
          editoptions: {
              enctype: "multipart/form-data"
            }, 
            edittype:'file',
            index: 'fileToUpload', 
            width: 150,
            align: "left",
            editable: true },
    ],
```

I've four days trying and looking for informations and tutoriasl!! help me!

Comment: Did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550304/jqgrid-upload-a-file-in-add-edit-dialog

Comment: Yes, I've seen that question. I'm using it. I think the problem is with the url of ajaxuploadfile.

Comment: I calls doajaxfileupload.php in the url, but nothing...

Comment: I'm using inlinenav...

Answer (score 0):

May be duplicate of :

> [File upload with jqgrid in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931468/file-upload-with-jqgrid-in-php)

I hope this will works.